# How to add context menu item to outlook when it in reading email mode

Tags: c#, outlook, outlook-addin, outlook-2013

So, I want create add-in which can read selected word at email and send it to the API by clicking on context menu. As for text selection everything is clear. But I stuck in creating context menu.

I search the web and found that we need add contextMenu item into the ribbon xml with specific **idMso**
But which of then I don't understand.

P.S.
I found the document with Outlook controls names here http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=6627

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I found it! **idMso="ContextMenuReadOnlyMailText"**